# Rectangle polygon is displayed as triangle in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon

I am wondering why a rectangle polygon that i have created on an official german surveying website (downloaded as compressed shape in a zip-file) is displayed as a triangle when loaded in qgis. mighty this have somethting to do with the chosen refence system (wgs84)?

at first this problem could temporarely be solved by starting the editing mode of this layer, but when ending editing the displayed rectangle is shown as a triangle again.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE, could you provide a link where you downloaded the zip and a screen shot of your screen in QGIS?

Comment: It probably has only 4 points instead of 5 making it a triangle

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a recent QGIS version, try turning OFF simplification for the layer:

[image]

When the layer is put into editing mode, simplification is automatically turned OFF, which is why the geometry displays as anticipated.

If you are not using QGIS 2.2, please upgrade to see if the bug has been fixed.